# Statistical count

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

I am reading the book["Heat and Thermodynamics"](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Heat_and_Thermodynamics.html?id=QjK3AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Mark Waldo Zemansky and Richard Dittman. In the chapter "Statistical Mechanics" it says if I have $N_{i}$ distinguishable particles in any of $g_{i}$ degenerate states associated with energy $\epsilon_{i}$ and if there is no restriction on multiple occupancy then there will ${(g_i)}^{N_i}$ number of ways in which those particles can be occupied. Then it says in case of indistinguishable particles the number of ways become $\dfrac{{(g_i)}^{N_i}}{N_{i}!}$.

when I do it in tabular method with $g_{i}$=3 and $N_{i}$=3 with the indistinguishable particles it gives 10 ways, not in agreement with what's written. Please help!

Comment: Could you tell the chapter, page etc. Is the  $Ni$ same as $N_{i}$ in $g_{i^{Ni}}/N_{i}$?

Comment: yes the same. 8e, page311-312

Comment: chap 13 Statistical Mechanics

Comment: Which edition? I have looked in the latest 13th edition there is no chapter named Statistical Mechanics.

Comment: Strange! I have a special Indian edition(8th ed) and an original 7ed pdf, both have the chapter. Heat and Thermodynamics by Zemansky and Dittman

Comment: which book are you talking about? University physics by sears and zemansky or someathing else? I have this :http://www.flipkart.com/sears-zemanskys-university-physics-modern-13th/p/itmdgt9k7hhhnf5n

Comment: Heat and Thermodynamics by Zemansky and Dittman

Comment: there is no objection on multiple occupancy! i can put 3 particles in a single state. there will be 8 ways. and yes according to the expression for indistinguishable particles the result is absurd, 9/2

Comment: I mistakenly deleted my previous comment. There are 10 ways $\dfrac{^3P_2}{2}+{^3P_3}+\dfrac{^3P_3}{3!}$: [(0,0,3) , (0,3,0) , (3,0,0)],[(0,1,2),(0,2,1),(1,2,0),(1,0,2),(2,1,0),2,0,1)] and last (1,1,1).

Comment: hm yes 10. i was wrong. what about the expression, it still troubles me

Comment: ('+1' and added fav.)Well I don't know. Actually the way the book reaches the expression is not graspable to me. In math we divide by $N!$ when talking of permutations. ${(g_i)}^{N_i}$ is not a permutation. Recently I have seen some well established books going wrong. Perhaps someone else could explain.

Comment: ${(g_i)}^{N_i}$ came as independent choices i think when we have distinguishable particles, every particle has $gi$ choices. thnks anyways

Comment: Use https://stackedit.io/  **${(g_i)}^{N_i}$=\${(g_i)}^{N_i}\$**. It came from the "_Fundamental principle of counting_" when all $N_i$ are distinguishable. Division of ${(g_i)}^{N_i}$ by $N!$ for indistinguishable particles is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following was the argument that the authors used to arrive at their expression:

> The first particle can choose to be in any one of the g states; the
>   second again. So N particles have a total of g*g*g*... choices - which
>   is the equation given. When they are indistinguishable you divide by N
>   factorial since that is how many times each combination shows up.

However, I come up with a different answer. Read on.

Your tabular example (3 distinguishable particles, 3 states) should look like this:

```
state |  1  |  2  |  3  |
------+-----+-----+-----+
 1    | 123 |     |     |
 2    | 12  |   3 |     |
 3    | 12  |     |   3 |
 4    | 1 3 |  2  |     |
 5    | 1   |  23 |     |
 6    | 1   |  2  |   3 |
 7    | 1 3 |     |  2  |
 8    | 1   |   3 |  2  |
 9    | 1   |     |  23 |
10    |  23 | 1   |     |
11    |  2  | 1 3 |     |
12    |  2  | 1   | 1 3 |
13    |   3 | 1   |     |
14    |     | 1 3 |   3 |
15    |     | 1   | 1 3 |
16    |   3 | 1   |     |
17    |     | 1 3 |     |
18    |     | 1   |   3 |
19    |  23 |     | 1   |
20    |  2  |   3 | 1   |
21    |  2  |     | 1 3 |
22    |   3 |  2  | 1   |
23    |     |  23 | 1   |
24    |     |  2  | 1 3 | 
25    |   3 |     | 12  | 
26    |     |   3 | 12  | 
27    |     |     | 123 |
```

27 states with distinguishable particles. Now for a small sample, as you pointed out, dividing the number of states by `N!` to compute the "indistinguishable" case doesn't make sense - it doesn't even lead to a whole number.

The "correct" answer for the second part is really the answer to the question: "in how many ways can we partition N identical particles with `(g-1)` partitions? Why `(g-1)`? Because one we put all the particles in a line, we need only `(g-1)` partitions to generate all possible states.

So there are `(N+g)` places to put `(g-1)` partitions. This we can solve - the answer is

$$\frac{(N+g)!}{(N+g-(g-1))!\cdot(g-1)!}$$

When N is very large (much larger than g), this becomes approximately

$$\frac{N^g}{g!}$$

Huh. That's funny. Now it's $$N^g$$ where before it was $$g^N$$.

Just to confirm the math - for our 3 particles, 3 states example, the equation becomes

$$\frac{5!}{3!\cdot2!}= \frac{120}{6\cdot2} = 10$$

as expected.

I have to conclude that the book is wrong... it wouldn't be the first time.

Clarification:

I realize that the "how do you partition `N` particles into g states" formula isn't very intuitive - so let me elaborate a little bit.  Here is one way to think about the problem. Draw `N+g-1` boxes in a row. Now place `g-1` check marks in arbitrary boxes (at most one per box). Starting from the left, count the number of "open" boxes. Each time you hit a marker, you reset your counter and start again. Since you had `N+g-1` boxes with `g-1` check marks, you will have reset your counter `g-1` times, and counted a total of N empty boxes (and placed these into `g` counters). Thus, this method gives you a possible partition of `N` into `g` states. And there are `(N+g-1)choose(g-1)` different ways to do this.

You can see the above equation mentioned (as equation (3)) in the paper http://www.linux.bucknell.edu/physics/ligare/hoStatMech.pdf

Comment: but with $g_{i}$=3 and $N_{i}$=3 that expression will give you 9/2!

Comment: You are right - this expression is "for large numbers". See my updated answer with the exact expression.